# How to specify latitude/longtitude in google ad preview tool?

Tags: advertising, google-ads

I've created an Adwords campaign targeting specific regions on the map using radius tool. However I don't see my ads when typing in my keywords, even though I've allowed google access to my location and I am in one of the regions I'm targeting.

So I'm trying to use google ad preview tool (https://ads.google.com/aw/diagnostic/AdPreview) and I see an error "The search location doesn't match this campaign's location targeting settings".

I'm trying to check whether my ads don't show since google doesn't know my correct location, or there is an error in campaign settings.

The problem is that the location input doesn't allow anything more specific than a city district, and I'd like to use latitude/longtitude instead. Is it possible?